# Mongoose helper method has no findOne method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I add helper methods to find and save objects in Mongoose.  A friend told me to use helper methods but I cannot get them to work after a day.  I always receive errors saying that either `findOne()` or `save()` does not exist OR that next callback is undefined (when node compiles ... before I execute it):

I've tried _schema.methods, _schema.statics... nothing works...

```
var email = require('email-addresses'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    strings = require('../../utilities/common/strings'),
    uuid = require('node-uuid'),
    validator = require('validator');

var _schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        default: uuid.v4
    },
    n: {                    // Name
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        index: true
    }
});

//_schema.index({
//    d: 1,
//    n: 1
//}, { unique: true });

_schema.pre('save', function (next) {

    if (!this.n || strings.isNullOrWhitespace(this.n)){
        self.invalidate('n', 'Domain name required but not supplied');
        return next(new Error('Domain name required but not supplied'));
    }

    var a = email.parseOneAddress('test@' + this.n);
    if (!a || !a.local || !a.domain){
        self.invalidate('n', 'Name is not valid domain name');
        return next(new Error('Name is not valid domain name'));
    }

    next();
});

_schema.statics.validateForSave = function (next) {

    if (!this.n || strings.isNullOrWhitespace(this.n)){
        return next(new Error('Domain name required but not supplied'));
    }

    var a = email.parseOneAddress('test@' + this.n);
    if (!a || !a.local || !a.domain){
        return next(new Error('Name is not valid domain name'));
    }

    next();
}

_schema.statics.findUnique = function (next) {

    this.validateForSave(function(err){
        if (err){ return next(err); }
        mongoose.model('Domain').findOne({ n: this.n }, next);
        //this.findOne({ n: this.n }, next);
    });
}

_schema.statics.init = function (next) {

    this.findUnique(function(err){
        if (err){ return next(err); }
        this.save(next);
    });
}

var _model = mongoose.model('Domain', _schema);

module.exports = _model;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're setting the `_id` to a `uuid` rather than just letting Mongoose generate the `_id`?

Comment: Because I don't want a sequential or nearly-sequential ID.

Comment: @G.Deward: Sorry, dude.  I tried.  According to the terms, I can only assign a bounty if I've edited the post.  Unfortunately, two peers rejected it (@bulk and @dleh)  saying I should comment instead.  Either they know something the terms don't specify or they didn't read my comments:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: @G.Deward give this a try as a schema method: `this.model("Domain").findOne(...)`

Comment: @cdbajorin: Tried that originally in the `findUnique()` method.  Didn't work.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running into issues because of your usage with `this`. Every time you enter a new function `this`'s context is changing. You can read more about `this` at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Additionally your callbacks aren't allowing anything to be passed into the mongoose method. For example if I was to create the most basic "save" method I  I would do the following:

```
_schema.statics.basicCreate = function(newDocData, next) {
  new _model(newDocData).save(next);
}
```

Now if I wanted to search the Domain collection for a unique document I would use the following:

```
_schema.statics.basicSearch = function(uniqueName, next) {
  var query = {n: uniqueName};

  _model.findOne(query, function(err, myUniqueDoc) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!myUniqueDoc) return next(new Error("No Domain with " + uniqueName + " found"));
    next(null, myNewDoc);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose has [built in validations](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) for what you are doing:

```
_schema.path("n").validate(function(name) {
    return name.length;
}, "Domain name is required");


_schema.path("n").validate(function(name) {

    var a = email.parseOneAddress("test@" + name);
    if (!a || !a.local || !a.domain) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}, "Name is not a valid domain name");
```

It returns a boolean. If false, it passes an error to the `.save()` callback with the stated message. For validating uniqueness:

```
_schema.path("n").validate(function(name, next) {

    var self = this;

    this.model("Domain").findOne({n: name}, function(err, domain) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        if (domain) {
            if (self._id === domain._id) {
                return next(true);
            }
            return next(false);
        }
        return next(true);
    });
}, "This domain is already taken");
```

You're using `self = this` here so that you can access the document inside the `findOne()` callback. `false` is being passed to the callback if the name exists and the result that is found isn't the document itself.

> I've tried _schema.methods, _schema.statics

To clarify, `.statics` operate on the Model, `.methods` operate on the document. Zane gave a good example of statics, so here is an example of methods:

```
_schema.methods.isDotCom = function() {

    return (/.com/).test(this.n);
}

var org = new Domain({n: "stuff.org"});
var com = new Domain({n: "things.com"});

org.isDotCom(); // false
com.isDotCom(); // true
```

**Opinion:** It's neat to have mongoose do validations, but it's very easy to forget it's happening. You also may want to have some validation in one area of your app while using different validations elsewhere. I'd avoid using most of it unless you definitively know you will have to do the same thing every time and will never NOT have to do it.

Methods/statics are a different story. It's very convenient to call `isDotCom()` instead of writing out a regex test every time you need to check. It performs a single and simple task that saves you some typing and makes your code more readable. Using methods for boolean checks can add a ton of readability. Defining statics like findByName (Zane's `basicSearch`) is great when you know you're going to do a simple query like that repeatedly.

Treat Mongoose as a utility, not as core functionality.